# Yaml dump for python lists uses inline format instead of hypen + space

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I have a python ordered dictionary like,

```
from collections import OrderedDict 
a = OrderedDict()
a['name'] = 'hello'
a['msgs'] = ['hello', 'world']
```

And I am converting it to YAML syntax as,

```
import yaml
with open("b.yaml", 'w') as stream:
  stream.write(yaml.dump(a))
```

It prints,

```
!!python/object/apply:collections.OrderedDict
- - [name, hello]
  - - msgs
    - [hello, world]
```

Whereas, I expected a more simpler YAML format as,

```
name : hello
msgs:
   - hello
   - world
```

How can I force YAML to print list items with `hypen + space` notation instead of JSON like `[a,b,c,d]` notation?

Why does PyYAML print an Ordered dict item as `[name, hello]` and not as `name : hello`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is confusing a few things together.  Starting with your initial example, you need explicit coding to cast your `a = {...}` to an `OrderedDict`.  Take that aside, this is your expect output:

```
>>> a = {
...   "name" : 'hello',
...   "msgs" : ['hello', 'world']
... }
>>> print(yaml.dump(a))
msgs: [hello, world]
name: hello
```

Which isn't exactly what you wanted.  If you read the [FAQ](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#Dictionarieswithoutnestedcollectionsarenotdumpedcorrectly) specifically on this issue, you will find that passing in `default_flow_style` to `dump` will yield your desired results

```
>>> print(yaml.dump(a, default_flow_style=False))
msgs:
- hello
- world
name: hello
```

As for why `OrderedDict` coming out like that, this is discussed in the section [YAML tags and Python types](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#YAMLtagsandPythontypes) in the documentation.  In short, this is done in consideration of Python's pickle protocol, and since `OrderedDict` are `list`s internally (which `list`s are ordered; `dict`s are unordered by definition), it gets the list-like representation.

Comment: Please note that the keys in your file are not in the expected order, which can cause problems if this file is checked into a revision controls system. Also the indentation of the sequences is not as the OP expected, but aligned with the `msgs` key.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't read the YAML specification you would expect mappings in YAML files to be ordered, as the text representation in a YAML file is ordered. Unfortunately this intuitive assumption is false, the [YAML 1.2](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2764196) explicitly states that this [should be interpreted as] an **unordered** set of *key: value pairs*.

This of course makes comparing YAML files using tools like `diff` virtually impossible if you use mappings and load/change/dump them, and makes checking these kind of file into revision control systems result in spurious extra revision that are semantically the same, but not syntactically.

I set out to improve PyYAML for other reasons as well (YAML 1.2 compatibility instead of the old 1.1 spec, preservation of comments, bug fixes), but [`ruamel.yaml`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml/) also preserves ordering as mappings if you use its `round_trip_dump`:

```
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.comments import CommentedMap as OrderedDict

a = OrderedDict()
a['name'] = 'hello'
a['msgs'] = ['hello', 'world']

with open("b.yaml", 'w') as stream:
    ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(a, stream, indent=5, block_seq_indent=3)
```

which gives you a file `b.yaml` with content:

```
name : hello
msgs:
   - hello
   - world
```

which is **exactly** what you expected.

Please note that I passed in the stream to the `round_trip_dump`, if you use PyYAML you should do this as well, as it is more efficient.
You need to use the `CommentedMap`, which is just a thin wrapper around OrderedDict/ordereddict that allows preservation of comments etc.
Default `indent` is 2 and `block_seq_indent` is 0.

If you load your file using `round_trip_dump`, you'll get a CommentedMap again in which the order of the keys will be as expected.